# NetBeans IDE installation fails on Ubuntu for RoR

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I am trying to set up NetBeans IDE on my Ubuntu machine for Ruby, but I am getting following error and installation get aborted. I have downloaded netbeans-6.9rc2-ml-ruby-linux.sh package.

Below are the commands I am running and error I was getting.

```
sh netbeans-6.9rc2-ml-ruby-linux.sh 
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
Aborted
```

Comment: I wonder why are you using netbeans for ROR development... The Ruby plugin is not supported anymore. Maybe you should consider other options like Emacs; Vim; Sublime or Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you going for version 6.9, provided latest version 7.1.

I would suggest you download `netbeans 7.1` for php and install the ruby on rails plugin using `Tools > Plugins`

It could fail because of either corrupted package or because of some missing dependency. If its because of dependency(It will log in the console), install them first and try it again.